# How to ungroup a weekly columns into days in python

Tags: python

[image: dataframe_1]

[image: dataframe_2]

I have two dataframe as shown in the diagram above. How do i split the dataframe_2 that is in weeks to break it down to days like dataframe_1 and combining the average value cinema generals by 7days into dataframe_1

In python if possible.

Answer (score 1):

use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe2['day'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe2["Year_week"],format="%Y_%w")
dataframe2.drop(columns="Year_week")
```